# Omniauth-facebook redirect_uri error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I am making a website login with devise (for regular login) and omniauth-facebook for facebook login, and the regular login is working perfectly except the omniauth. I followed https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview
this doc. And the Error I get from the response were:

> Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in
>   the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100

And I searched around and found that there is a pull request that fixes this problem..? https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/220 Does anyone know how to fix it while the pull request get merged into master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can point to a different source for the omniauth-facebook gem in your Gemfile like this:

```
gem "omniauth-facebook", git: "https://github.com/gioblu/omniauth-facebook"
```

It will use the one with the patch in it.

Comment: Thanks, the repo owner fixed it in v3.0